# Macros Visual Basic How can I sum to a selected range area like this Set rango = Range("A7:A7+8")

Tags: vba, excel

Dim rango As Range, celda As Range

Set rango = Range("A7:A7+8")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps .Resize like this,

```
Set rango = Range("A7").Resize(8, 1)
```

It really isn't clear from your narrative which direction to expand by 8 somethings. The above expands A7 to A7:A14 (total 8 rows).

Answer (score 0):

There are several mothod. It is same.

```
Set rango = Range("A7:A" & 7 + 8)
Set rango = Range("A7", "A" & 7 + 8)
Set rango = Range("A7").Resize(9)
```

Comment: How can I contact you look I want to make a amortization schedule calculator but I want that whenever the user can change fixed payment and for that purpose I want that it cycles all the time and spot the right cell where the user makes a higher payment so I can do a bunch of things thanks